# MBProgressHUD in UITabBarController

Tags: uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, mbprogresshud

This has been annoying me for a good week, as i have previously used MBProgressHUD in prior versions of the app.

No matter how I try to set the code in my project to show MBProgressHUD, I always receive 'Apple Mach-O Linker Error':"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Home.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Below is the source code I'm using in my application m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Home.h"
#import "SSFB.h"
#import "SST.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize  navigationController = _navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *home = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *ssfb = [[SSFB alloc] initWithNibName:@"SSFB" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *sst = [[SST alloc] initWithNibName:@"SST" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[home, ssfb, sst];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
@end
```

Home.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface Home : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
IBOutlet UIWebView *homeWebView;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *homeNavBar;
UIAlertView *loadingAlert;
UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingTicker;
MBProgressHUD *HUD;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *homeNavBar;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIAlertView *loadingAlert;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIAlertView *loadingTicker;
-(IBAction)refreshhomeWebView:(id)sender;
-(void)myTask;
-(void)showWithLabel;

@end
```

And finally the Home.m file:

```
@implementation Home
@synthesize homeNavBar = _homeNavBar, loadingAlert, loadingTicker = _loadingTicker;

-(void)myTask{
while(homeWebView.loading){
}
}
- (void)showWithLabel {
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)homeWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error");
 if ([error code] == -1009 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"no Internet connection"]){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There is currently no internet access." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
if ([error code] == -1001 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"timed out"]){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The connection, please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
if ([error code] == -1004 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"can't connect to host"]){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can not connect to the webpage's host at this time, please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
else{
       }
}
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)homeWebView{
[self showWithLabel];
    NSLog(@"start load");
    }   

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)homeWebView{
}

-(IBAction)refreshhomeWebView:(id)sender{
    [homeWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.socialstarsclub.com"] ]];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", @"Home");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_30"];
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    [self.homeNavBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[homeWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.socialstarsclub.com"] ]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I've tried variations of code for 'showWithLable' trying to set the HUD on the highest view heir achy but always receive the same errors, can anyone see what could be a simple mistake in my coding?

Answer (score 3):

Wow. For some reason with Clean and Build (Command + Shift + K), and also following this thread, [Got error in implementing EGOPhotoViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915493/got-error-in-implementing-egophotoviewer), I had to add both MBProgressHUD.h & MBProgressHUD.m under the compiled Sources, in targets menu.

Then change:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
```

&

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
```

To:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.tabBarController.view];
```

&

```
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:HUD];
```